# Program that guesses each position of the password

Tags: python, loops

I'm a beginner in Python and my assignment is to guess the password by running through the length of the unknown, random password and then replacing that position with the correct letter/number. I know it involves running the code until a match is found but I'm stuck.

> You are to write a program that will try to guess each position of the password.  The program must use a function that contains the code to hack the password.
>   Use of lists and methods/functions such as list( ) and .join will be helpful.
>   You should begin by displaying a string made up of asterisks (e.g.  *******)  equal to the length of the generated password. 
>   As you match each letter/number in the secret password, replace the asterisk in that same position with that letter/number.
>   The output should look like this:

**Password is *yfdszk***

```
Hacking...
Found match at position 2
*d****
Found match at position 1
*fd***
Found match at position 5
*fd**k
Found match at position 3
*fds*k
Found match at position 0
yfds*k
Found match at position 4
yfdszk
I did it! yfdszk
```

Here is my code:

```
import random
characters="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
charList=list(characters)
def generatePassword(pwLen):
    pw=""
    for i in range(pwLen):
        rand=int(random.randint(0,len(charList)-1))
        pw=pw + (charList[rand])
        pwList = list(pw)
    return pw
def hackPassword(pw):
    r`enter code here`and=int(random.randint(0,len(charList)-1))
    pw=pw + (charList[rand])
    pwList = list(pw)
    asterisk = "*" * len(pw)
    asteriskList = list(asterisk)
    print asterisk
    for numbers in range(len(charList)):
        if charList == pwList[]:
            password = pw[:index] + "*" +  pw[index+1:]
password=generatePassword(8)
# display secret
print "Password is " + password
hackPassword(password)
```

I need to be able to guess the password, using a for loop to go through the length of the password, then finding a match, and then replacing that asterisk with the found letter/number.

But I'm getting this error message:

```
IndexError: list index out of range on line 20
```

Comment: This is a rather poor example of how passwords actually work. I notice this is basically the game of Hangman so maybe just think of it as that instead.

Comment: Do you understand what the error message means?

Answer (score 0):

Although your sample run is flawed, I believe I understand the gist of what you're trying to do. You generate a random password and then represent it with asterisks, so that the length is shown. Then, for each character in `characters="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"` you check if it matches any of the chars in the password.  By the time you've run through it, you're done. So, you're going to need a double nested loop. I won't write it for you, but i'll give you a hint, in pseudocode:

```
generate a random password
make a corresponding 'fake' password of the same length of asterisks
for char in charList:
    for position in actual password:
        if char matches that position:
            change the asterisk to that char in the fake password
            if my fake password is cracked (no more asterisks):
                print('Whoohoo!')
                go home, you're done
```

Hope this helps!  Getting the logic right is always the hardest part of programming!

As a side note, I got the above understanding because I noticed in your example that you are cracking the password in alphabetical order... d-f-k-s-y-z...